Hacer funcionar un algoritmo pseudocodigo en PSeInt
Estoy haciendo un proyecto de optimización de posgrado de la Universidad Tecnológica de Bolívar en Cartagena, Colombia. Y yo quiero hacer un algoritmo en PSeInt que haga:

entre a la base de datos por la ubicación: 'E:\REHABILITAR 2.accdb'
busque en el 1 de abril cuantas citas fueron agendadas
sume el número de citas agendadas del 1 de abril
de esa suma cuente cuantos pacientes son hombre o mujer

Este es mi código de momento:
Funcion AbrirBaseDeDatos <- BaseDeDatos ( ruta Como Cadena )
Devolver baseDeDatosAbierta;
FinFuncion

Funcion EjecutarConsulta <- Resultado ( baseDeDatos Como BaseDeDatos, consulta Como Cadena )
    Devolver resultadoConsulta
FinFuncion
// Define las otras funciones necesarias para tu programa
Algoritmo ConsultarCitas
    // Declaración de variables
    Definir conexion, consulta, resultado, citas, totalCitas, totalHombres, totalMujeres Como Entero
    Definir fechaInicio, fechaFin Como Cadena
    Definir paciente, genero Como Caracter
    // Conectarse a la base de datos
    conexion <- AbrirBaseDeDatos("E:\REHABILITAR 2.accdb");
    // Consultar citas del 1 de abril
    fechaInicio = "01/04/2024"
    fechaFin = "02/04/2024"
    consulta = "SELECT * FROM citas WHERE fecha >= '" + fechaInicio + "' AND fecha < '" + fechaFin + "'"
    resultado = EjecutarConsulta(conexion, consulta)
    // Contar citas y pacientes por género
    citas = 0
    totalCitas = 0
    totalHombres = 0
    totalMujeres = 0
    Mientras haya filas en resultado hacer
        paciente = ObtenerValorDeColumna(resultado, "paciente")
        genero = ObtenerValorDeColumna(resultado, "genero")
        Si genero = "H" entonces
            totalHombres = totalHombres + 1
        Sino
            totalMujeres = totalMujeres + 1
        FinSi
        citas = citas + 1
        SiguienteFila(resultado)
    FinMientras
    totalCitas = totalHombres + totalMujeres
    
    // Mostrar resultados
    Escribir("Total citas el 1 de abril: " + citas)
    Escribir("Total citas: " + totalCitas)
    Escribir("Total hombres: " + totalHombres)
    Escribir("Total mujeres: " + totalMujeres)
    
    // Cerrar conexión
    CerrarBaseDeDatos(conexión)
FinAlgoritmo

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero tengo un problema, que el código me está generando errores:
<sin_titulo>: Sintaxis Incorrecta: 33 errores.
Lin 1 (inst 1): ERROR 249: Se esperaba coma(,) o tipo de pasaje (Por Copia o Por Referencia).
Lin 5 (inst 1): ERROR 249: Se esperaba coma(,) o tipo de pasaje (Por Copia o Por Referencia).
Lin 5 (inst 1): ERROR 249: Se esperaba coma(,) o tipo de pasaje (Por Copia o Por Referencia).
Lin 2 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 6 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 11 (inst 1): ERROR 48: Identificador no válido (RESULTADO).
Lin 15 (inst 1): ERROR 202: El identificador ABRIRBASEDEDATOS no corresponde a un arreglo o subproceso
Lin 17 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 18 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 19 (inst 1): ERROR 304: Falta operador (antes de la cadena de caracteres).
Lin 19 (inst 1): ERROR 304: Falta operador (antes de la cadena de caracteres).
Lin 19 (inst 1): ERROR 304: Falta operador (antes de la cadena de caracteres).
Lin 19 (inst 1): ERROR 304: Falta operador (antes de la cadena de caracteres).
Lin 19 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 20 (inst 1): ERROR 310: La función retorna un valor, debe ser parte de una expresión (RESULTADO).
Lin 20 (inst 1): ERROR 266: Los argumentos para invocar a un Función deben ir entre paréntesis.
Lin 22 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 23 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 24 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 25 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 26 (inst 1): ERROR 284: Se esperaba solo una expresión (condición).
Lin 27 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 28 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 30 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 32 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 34 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 35 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 37 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
Lin 40 (inst 1): ERROR 295: No coinciden los tipos (+). Los operandos deben ser de igual tipo.
Lin 41 (inst 1): ERROR 295: No coinciden los tipos (+). Los operandos deben ser de igual tipo.
Lin 42 (inst 1): ERROR 295: No coinciden los tipos (+). Los operandos deben ser de igual tipo.
Lin 43 (inst 1): ERROR 295: No coinciden los tipos (+). Los operandos deben ser de igual tipo.
Lin 46 (inst 1): ERROR 106: Instrucción no válida.
No se que estoy haciendo mal, o si en Opciones de Lenguaje (Perfiles) debo cambiar algo?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! si es pseint, no es pseudocodigo... es pseint, es un lenguaje que parece pseudocodigo... y el error es en la linea 1, y de ahi en mas, tenes que solucionar 1 por 1... No hay ningun lenguaje que te deje nombrar una variable como "ruta Como Cadena" con espacios... de ahi en mas, todo es un problema...
